# Flutter Google Sign In Keeps Asking for Permission

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-signin

I am working with the Google Sign In auth through Firebase but each time I test the app in iOS Google keeps asking for permissions whenever I login with Google Sing In. In Android it only asks for permission once.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

This is my Google Sign In code:

```
class AuthService {

  signInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? gUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication gAuth = await gUser!.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: gAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: gAuth.idToken,
    );
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
}
```

I tried to find another code but none of them worked!

[image: This is the Permission pop-up screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have enabled Google authentication in firebase and is using the updated `google-services.json` file and `GoogleService-Info.plist` files.

You can make use of [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package.

Also, please add the scope when instantiating Google signin

```
GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
    'email',
  ],
);

GoogleSignInAccount? gAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final credential = await gAccount!.authentication;
```

Comment: I tried it but it keeps asking for permission :( thank you for your answer though!

Comment: @DavidLee could you specify which permission it is asking?

Comment: Yes! It is the following:

"{App} wants to use 'google.com' to Sign In.
This allows the app and website to share information about you."

Then the user is given the option to 'Cancel' or 'Continue'

Comment: Please share a screenshot if possible

Comment: I couldn't upload it in the comments section, so I edited and uploaded the original post. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This is very normal. Please press continue and proceed.